# Навешивание Angular 7 на HTML генерируемый сервером. Как лучше?

Tags: html, angular

Проектируем блочный визуальный конструктор сайтов. Сервер будет отдавать размеченный готовый HTML блоков, но весь визуальный интерфейс, все контролы,  настройки каждого блока хотим обрабатывать в приложении на Angular 7.

Подскажите best practive, какие-либо статьи или материалы по навешиванию Angular приложения (навешивание событий, модификация HTML, и т.д.) на статичный (сформированный сервером) HTML.

Понимаю, что в идеальном случае весть HTML должен формироваться из самого приложения Angular, но реальность такова, что HTML, который должен "ожить" приходит с сервера.

Comment: может вы пометите ответ галочкой либо напишите что вам непонятно? может стоит что-то дополнить, а то ответ так 4 мес уже висит 

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нет никаких best practice, с этим немногие сталкиваются, но регистрирование обработчиков событий в Angular работает так же, как и в обычном JavaScript. Самое большое преимущество ручного регистрирования обработчиков событий - производительность. Такой шаблон:

```
<button (click)="clickMe()">Click me</button>
```

Компилируется в `NodeDef` - определение узла. В рантайме у этого объекта будет свойство `outputDefs` (массив), который будет содержать объекты `OutputDef`, в случае с узлом `button` объект будет таков:

```javascript
{
    type: OutputType.ElementOutput, // 0
    target: 'component',
    eventName: 'click',
    propName: 'clickMe'
}
```

Далее Angular регистрирует обработчики событий через класс `EventManager`, фактически все, что он делает это:

```typescript
addEventListener(nodeDef.element, outputDef.eventName, componentInstance[outputDef.propName]);
```

Все, да не все. Эти действия происходят в зоне Angular, поэтому на любой асинхронное событие Angular запускает механизм обнаружения изменений по всему дереву.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же у нас будет готовый HTML, то мы можем регистрировать обработчики событий вне зоны и контролировать механизм обнаружения изменений, как пример возьмем компонент, в котором есть элемент, который сеттит `innerHTML` через атрибут:

```typescript
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <div [innerHTML]="html"></div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
    public html: SafeHtml = null!;

    private listeners: Function[] = [];

    constructor(
        private zone: NgZone,
        private renderer: Renderer2,
        private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
        private host: ElementRef<HTMLUnknownElement>,
        private service: SomeService
    ) {
        this.service.getHTML().subscribe((html) => {
            this.setHTML(html);
        });
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.listeners.forEach((listener) => listener());
    }

    private setHTML(html: string): void {
        this.html = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);

        this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            // обработчики событий мы должны регистрировать после того
            // как засеттится `innerHTML`, поэтому используем `setTimeout`
            setTimeout(() => this.addEventListeners());
        });
    }

    private addEventListeners(): void {
        const node = this.host.nativeElement.querySelector('some-element')!;

        this.listeners.push(
            this.renderer.listen(node, 'click', (e: MouseEvent) => {
                console.log(e);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

А вообще вы можете не знать на каких элементах вызываются события, но вы могли бы формировать HTML на сервере с подсказками, например:

```
<button data-event="click" data-method="clickMe">Click me</button>
<div data-event="mousemove" data-method="handleMousemove">Mousemove me</div>
```

В компоненте достаточно будет обойти все узлы и проверить свойства из `dataset`:

```typescript
const nodes = this.host.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('*');

nodes.forEach((node: HTMLElement) => {
    const { event, method } = node.dataset;
    if (event && method && typeof this[method] === 'function') {
        this.listeners.push(this.renderer.listen(node, event, this[method]));
    }
});
```

А еще осторожней с контекстом, нужно тогда использовать стрелочные функции для методов:

```typescript
private handleMousemove = () => {}
```

Или биндить:

```typescript
this.renderer.listen(node, event, this[method].bind(this))
```

Да, кстати, обязательно нужно использовать `DomSanitizer.prototype.bypassSecurityTrustHtml` ибо Angular для защиты от XSS вообще удаляет все атрибуты и прочее регулярками, оставляя только элемент и текст внутри него.